# Mysql error 1093: cannot insert into target table

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

The error is below. How can I insert without getting this error?

> Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'ROLE_PERMISSION' for
>   update in FROM clause 0,00095 sec

The code:

```
INSERT INTO ROLE_PERMISSION(ID, PERMISSION, ROLE_ID) VALUES ((SELECT MAX(ID)+1 from ROLE_PERMISSION), 'MOBILE_APP_CONNECTION', (SELECT ID FROM ROLES WHERE NAME='PROJECT_USER'));
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp You can do that like this

Comment: I need to solve the problem, nothing with the way of using

Comment: can you tell me data type of ID, PERMISSION, ROLE_ID

Comment: then add the schema of the 2-3 tables

Comment: @JayShankarGupta Int, String, Int.